# Copy multiple feature classes in FME without merging

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I am trying to create an FME workspace that reads a series of feature classes from an Oracle SDE database and copies them to another Oracle SDE database, one by one. The key thing is I do not want to merge them into a single feature class. Do I need to have multiple writers, or can I use some kind of "dynamic" setting to maintain separate tables? I'm not finding very much documentation about this type of workflow. I found this article:

[Pass a List of Tables or Layers to an FME Reader using Python Scripted Parameters](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/684/pass-a-list-of-tables-or-layers-to-an-fme-reader-u.html)

but I would prefer to have all of my sources contained within the workspace.

Comment: Note: FME 2016 has the FeatureWriter now http://blog.safe.com/2016/01/fmeevangelist143/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one writer (to the SDE database) but multiple outputs for each feature class.
[image]
In fact if I specify my Reader feature classes first, when I create my output Writer it asks me if I want to create matching output feature classes, and then all I need to do is link them (and add any transformers between them if desired)

[image]
I believe there is a way to combine them into one Writer output and have it dynamically output to the correct feature classes, but I have never had success in getting this to work.